# MembershipUser.ChangePassword method returns false at all time

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0, asp.net-membership

i having trouble with mvc4 membership issue , i cant change the user's password like

```
public bool SetNewPassword(string newPassword)
    {
        var generatedPassword = membershipUser.ResetPassword();
        return membershipUser.ChangePassword(generatedPassword, newPassword);
    }
```

it is always returning false , i checked that the user is not lockedout , and is approved, how can i handle this? please help , i am driving myself crazy upon this point.

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing in `oldPassword` and not resetting it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the simplemembership provider for your MVC 4 project you can reset the password with the following code...

> public bool ResetPassword(string newPassword)
>           {
>
> ```
>         bool result = false;
>
>         if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
>         {
>             var member = Membership.GetUser();
>
>             string token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(member.UserName);
>             result = WebSecurity.ResetPassword(token, newPassword);
>         }
>
>         return result;
>     }
> ```

Comment: Hi Simon, now i am working on that , since MysqlSimpleMembership's generatepasswordreset token returns null , but thanks for effort.

Comment: I didn't know you are using MYSql. Where did you get the MySqlSimpleMemebership provider from please? SimpleMembership is designed for SQL Server centric databases so you'll likely have a few issues. Please mark my answer up if it was useful.

Comment: Connector/Net 6.9  Release Notes
------------------------------------
Welcome to the release notes for Connector/Net 6.9

What's new in 6.9
--------------------

- Simple Membership Web Provider
- Site Map Web Provider
- Personalization Web Provider
- MySql Fabric support
I counted on this doc , Simon